# Legend for regression lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I am plotting multiple regression lines based on different data sets in one graph. I would like a legend to show what each regression line is, but I cannot get the legend to show up at all. Is there any way to do this without adding the points to the graph? I've tried using 'fullrange=TRUE', but it is not working.

```
ggplot() +
  #regression line 1
  # geom_point(data=young,stat='identity', position='identity', aes(x=day,y=in.temp)) + scale_colour_gradient(low='yellow', high='#de2d26') +
  geom_smooth(data=young, aes(x=day,y=in.temp,colour='Young'), method='lm',fullrange=TRUE,size=2,color='#f08080',fill='#f08080',show.legend=TRUE) +
  #regression line 2
  # geom_point(data=old,aes(x=day, y=in.temp)) + scale_colour_gradient(low='yellow', high='#de2d26') +
  geom_smooth(data=old, aes(x=day, y=in.temp, colour='Old'), method='lm',fullrange=TRUE,size=2,color='#87ceeb',fill='#87ceeb',show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,38)) +scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:25)
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You have `color = "Young` and `color = "Old"` in your `aes()`, which is good. What you need to do is add set the colors with `scale_color_manual()` instead of putting `color='#f08080'` in the `geom_smooth` layer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I'm still fairly new at r and ggplot.